# Putting links next to each other - CSS mobile styles

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have my links stacked vertically in my default CSS, but I'm trying to push the nav to the top of the page and set them horizontally in mobile.  Can't seem to make it happen.
The site is in WordPress, which makes determining the names of elements difficult.

```
#sidebaar a, #sidebaar li {
text-align:right;
clear:both;
```

}

```
#sidebaar{
width:150px;
text-align, right;
align-content:right;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
```

}

In media styles:

```
 #sidebaar a, #sidebaar ul li, #sidebaar ul li a{
display:inline;
clear:none;

} #sidebaar{
    width:100%;
}
```

My site can be viewed here - http://www.ubart320.org/students/mariaroo/gallery/

Answer (score 0):

Your `header` and `nav`elements contain (in different rules) both `width` and `max-width` definitions of 150px for max-width and 160/360px for width which prevent your menu from getting any wider.

You have to define `width: 100%;` and `max-width: none;` for both, if necessary, add `!important to those values`

Answer (score 0):

You have some funky code going on. For some reason you have two menus showing on mobile. However, I set the second menu to `display: none;` and applied these styles to get an acceptable result (apply this to you mobile styles):

```
nav{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}
ul#menu-menu-2{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#menu-menu-2 li{
  margin: 0 2.5px;
}
```

See the end result below. It looks like you still have some work to do on the photo grid, but the horizontal nav is acceptable. Let me know if you have any further questions!

[image]

Comment: ha, those comments. Did you set display: none to the 'sidebaar' element? Thanks for your help

Comment: @maria No, I set #sidebar to `display: none;`. I'm not sure why WordPress is duplicating your main menu on mobile. You might be able to fix it in configuration, rather than using `display: none`. Hope this helps!